# Overriding `tcp.publish_port` breaks clustering when elasticsearch is in a container

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to run an elasticsearch cluster with each es-node running in its own container.  These containers are deployed using [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) across several machines that may be running other unrelated containers.  To avoid port conflicts each port a container exposes is assigned a random value.  These random ports are consistent across all running containers of the same type.  In other words, all running es-node containers map port 9300 to the same random number.

Here's the config I'm using:

```
network:
  host: 0.0.0.0

plugin:
  mandatory: cloud-aws

cluster:
  name: ${ES_CLUSTER_NAME}

discovery:
  type: ec2
  ec2:
    groups: ${ES_SECURITY_GROUP}
    any_group: false
  zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

transport:
  tcp.port: 9300
  publish_port: ${_INSTANCE_PORT_TRANSPORT}

cloud.aws:
  access_key: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
  secret_key: ${AWS_SECRET_KEY}
  region: ${AWS_REGION}
```

In this case `_INSTANCE_PORT_TRANSPORT` is the port that 9300 is bound to on the host machine.  I've confirmed that all the environment variables used above are set correctly.  I'm also setting `network.publish_host` to the host machine's local IP via a command line arg.

When I forced `_INSTANCE_PORT_TRANSPORT` (and in turn `transport.publish_port`) to be 9300, everything worked great, but as soon as it's given a random value, nodes can no longer connect to each other.  I see errors like this using `logger.discovery=TRACE`:

```
ConnectTransportException[[][10.0.xxx.xxx:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: ConnectException[Connection refused: /10.0.xxx.xxx:9300];
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannelsLight(NettyTransport.java:952)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:916)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNodeLight(NettyTransport.java:888)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLight(TransportService.java:267)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$3.run(UnicastZenPing.java:395)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems like the port a node binds to is the same as the port it pings while trying to connect to other nodes.  Is there any way to make them different?  If not, what's the point of `transport.publish_port`?

Comment: Could you post the beginning of the log up to `[.........][INFO ][node                     ] [My Node Name] started` for the node that you start?

Comment: Will do.  The cluster has two machines named Gateway and Doctor Spectrum.  Here the logs from both machines: https://gist.github.com/xavi-/6ecc4ba16b39680fb28c8fb25307bcc7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the `discovery-ec2` plugin works is that it's collecting a list of IP addresses using AWS EC2 API and use this list as unicast list of nodes.

But it does not collect any information from the running cluster. Obviously the node is not yet connected!
So it does not know anything about the `publish_port` of other nodes.

It just adds an IP address. And that's all. Elasticsearch then [is using the default port](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/plugins/discovery-ec2/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/discovery/ec2/AwsEc2UnicastHostsProvider.java#L174-L179) which is 9300.

So there is nothing you can do IMO to fix that in the short time.

But we can imagine adding a new feature which is close to what has been implemented for [Google Compute Engine](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-gce#changing-default-transport-port). We are using a specific metadata to get this port from the GCE APIs.

We could do the same for Azure and EC2. Do you want to [open an issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/new) so we can track the effort?